# explanation for Common Iterator mistake

Tags: java, collections, iterator

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class lesson {
     static void printAll(ArrayList<String> names, int len)
      {
         Iterator it = names.iterator();
         while( it.hasNext() )
         {
         if( ((String)it.next()).length() == len)
         System.out.println( it.next() );
         }
      }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("Jan");
        names.add("Ivan");
        names.add("Tom");
        names.add("George");
        printAll(names,3);
    }
}
```

why is the output Ivan, George, shouldn't it print only names with length 3 (which are Jan and Tom)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if( ((String)it.next()).length() == len)
         System.out.println( it.next() );
         }
```

`it.next()` advances iterator to one element.  You are doing `it.next()` twice.

`if( ((String)it.next()).length() == len)` advances one time and now iterator points to next()

Change it to something like below:

```
 it.next() prints next() element in iterator.
      {
       //Get once.
        String nextName = (String)it.next();
         if( nextName .length() == len)
         System.out.println(nextName  );
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

Do yourself a favor and learn to use the *enhanced for* loop, it would prevent you from making the mistake you did:

```
 static void printAll(ArrayList<String> names, int len)
 {
     for (String name : names) {
       if (name.length() == len)
         System.out.println( name );
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you are calling iterator.next() twice, the second call would advance. follow the below approach, store it in a variable and do the check

```
 Iterator it = names.iterator();
   String next =(String)it.next(); 
         while( it.hasNext() )
         {
         if( (next).length() == len)
         System.out.println( next );
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change below to avoid two `it.next()` calls as its comparing the length and availability of one element and tries to print the other.

```
    while( it.hasNext() )
     {
       if( ((String)it.next()).length() == len)
       System.out.println( it.next() );
     }
```

To

```
    while( it.hasNext() )
     {
       String element = (String)it.next();
       if(element.length() == len)
          System.out.println( element);
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want value two times then store it in some variable. If you call it twice then your iterator will move ahead and that is why while printing it is giving you that result

```
while( it.hasNext() )
     {
       String str = it.next();
        if( (str.length() == len)
          System.out.println(str);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `it.next()`

1. Returns the current element in the collection.
2. **And** advances the position of the iterator.

You call `next()` twice in the body of the loop. You should either make sure to only call it once:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = names.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String name = it.next();
    if (name.length() == len) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Or use the *enhanced for loop*:

```
for (String name : names) {
    if (name.length() == len) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. Print only 3 characters of every string from ArrayList:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class lesson {
 static void printAll(ArrayList<String> names, int len)
  {
     for (String s : names)
     if (s.length() == len)
     {
     System.out.println(s);
     }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add("Jan")
    names.add("Ivan");
    names.add("Tom");
    names.add("George");
    printAll(names,3);
   }
}
```

Comment: in your example, you don't seem to have used the Iterator correct? it's a different method for achieving the same result?